# PHP 4.4.9 and matching mysql, phpmyadmin & apache

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, phpmyadmin

I'm pretty new to linux, php and mysql.
I am running CentOS 5 and I have to install PHP 4.4.9 (this is the required version) on it.
I also want to install apache, mysql and php myadmin but do not know which version match PHP 4.4.9 and how to install.
Pls help me in installing all the above given 4 (i.e. PHP 4.4.9 and corresponding mysql, apache & php myadmin) on CentOS 5.
If there is any additional configuration required, let me know them too.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You really don't want to install that version... It reached its end of life and might even contain security holes.

Comment: Why in God's name is PHP 4.4.9 required?  This was released in 2008..

Comment: you can install the higher versions? is there any problem with higher versions?

Comment: because the hosting company is using 4.4.9 and have to prepare the development environment in virtual machine

Comment: In this case you ***really need*** to change the hosting company (or tell them that you will unless they switch to a recent PHP version)! Using such an old version is absolutely irresponsible!

Comment: Asado Qureshi kindly check my answer..

Answer (score 0):

You shall NEVER install php4 anymore!

Installing PHP,MySQL and Apache is no big deal, here is a detailed tutorial (for CentOS 5):
http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-centos-5.3-lamp

Answer (score 0):

I must suggest you to upgrade your hosting environment. But for now if you want to go with that only then follow the steps provided in following link

http://devblog.darkobulatovic.com/?p=4